# Google Test suite camera

Tags: camera, google-smart-home

It's normal that my camera stream display doesn't support without 100% passing the test suite?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYz3O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Only the testing of WebRTC protocol is currently supported by the Google Test Suite.
Other camera protocols (e..g HLS, DASH etc) are not supported at the moment.
Hence, this is the reason why you are probably seeing that message.